# Add an object that has a many to many relationship with the current user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a project and user Model that inherits the default identity class.

These two share a many to many relationship.

```
    public class Project
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AppUser> users { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Project> projects { get; set; }  
    }
```

In my projects controller I display all the projects that belong to the current user;
(I check for the user with the user id)

```
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var userId = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            IEnumerable<Project> objProjectList = _unitOfWork.Project.Where(userId);
            return View(objProjectList);
        }
```

and on the post method I'm trying to add the current user to the newly created project object to establish the relation between these two i.e. (this user is a member of this project)
I've used dependency injection to inject usermanager that uses my custom user class (Appuser, which inherits the default scaffolded identity)

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(Project obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                AppUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
                obj.users.Add(user);
                _unitOfWork.Project.Add(obj);
                _unitOfWork.Project.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(obj);
            }

        }
```

However I'm getting the following error;

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

What exactly am I doing wrong? Should I be adding the user some other way?

I'd appreciate any input, thanks.

Comment: I know what null is, when debugging the object itself is not null, I can see all the properties I'm asking WHY its null not what null is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model design:

```
public ICollection<AppUser> users { get; set; }
```

`ICollection` is an interface, you can't use it to add something direcetly, Or you will get `NullReferenceException`. You can create an instance, and then use it to add what you want.

```
AppUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

//create an instance.
List<AppUser> users = new List<AppUser>();

users.Add(user);

obj.users = users;
_unitOfWork.Project.Add(obj);
_unitOfWork.Project.Save();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```